# Making std::optional - no viable conversion

Tags: c++

I have a custom class, fairly simple one - DecimalEx.

I have a variable of type

```
std::optional<DecimalEx> myVariable = std::nullopt;
```

when I try to do an assignment like this:

```
// dialect::rfd::Decimal_v1 myInitParam
myVariable = DecimalEx(myInitParam);
```

the compiler complains that there is no viable conversion from the class to optional.

I tried different things, I created copy constructor (because it was complaining about it before),
I tried static_cast, I am not sure what the issue is.

My class header, the the implementation has some trivial constructors to initialize variables:

```
namespace test {

    class DecimalEx
    {
    public:
        DecimalEx(const DecimalEx&);
        explicit DecimalEx(int64_t value);
        explicit DecimalEx(double value);
        explicit DecimalEx(int64_t value, int8_t scale);
        DecimalEx(dialect::rfd::Decimal_v1 value);


// ... some methods

        inline bool operator==(const DecimalEx& x) const { return m_unscaledInteger == x.m_unscaledInteger; }
        inline bool operator!=(const DecimalEx& x) const { return m_unscaledInteger != x.m_unscaledInteger; }

    private:
        int64_t m_unscaledInteger;
        const double m_power;
        constexpr const static signed char s_default_scale = 9;
        constexpr const static std::array<double, 256> power_table = create_power_table();
    };

}

// constructor 
DecimalEx::DecimalEx(const DecimalEx& value)
    : m_unscaledInteger(value.m_unscaledInteger),
    m_power(value.m_power)
{
    // Intentionally left blank
}

DecimalEx::DecimalEx(dialect::rfd::Decimal_v1 value)
        : m_unscaledInteger(value.value()),
          m_power(power_table[static_cast<size_t>(value.scale()) + 128ul])
{
    // Intentionally left blank
}
```

error:

```
No viable conversion from 'core::DecimalEx' to 'std::optional<core::DecimalEx>' 
candidate template ignored: requirement '__and_<std::__not_<std::is_same<std::optional<ctc::ref_data::core::DecimalEx>, ctc::ref_data::core::DecimalEx>>, std::__not_<std::is_same<std::in_place_t, ctc::ref_data::core::DecimalEx>>, std::i... 
candidate template ignored: could not match 'optional<_Up>' against 'core::DecimalEx' 
candidate template ignored: could not match 'optional<_Up>' against 'core::DecimalEx' 
explicit constructor is not a candidate 
explicit constructor is not a candidate 
explicit constructor is not a candidate 
explicit constructor is not a candidate
```

I am new to C++ coming from Java and I am sure I don't understand something simple I need to do.

Comment: This will depend on how your type `MyClass` is defined. It must satisfy the requirements of `std::optional::operator=`.

Comment: sorry, no matching constructor was the initial error and I made a copy constructor for that. I still am not sure why I needed to do that, but I guess I am pass that point.

Comment: *I created copy constructor* `DecimalEx(DecimalEx&)` this is not a proper copy constructor. It does not work with temoraries. Take a better look at your book.

Comment: Easy workaround: `myVariable = DecimalEx(myInitParam);` -> `myVariable.emplace(myInitParam);`

Comment: first link for "copy constructor cpp" is this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copy-constructor-in-cpp/ and it doesn't have const (but has in the implementation). I fixed it

Comment: @RomanGoyenko read [Copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) on [cppreference.com](https://cppreference.com) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fix a copy constructor

```
  DecimalEx(const DecimalEx&);
```

then you move forward and get other a short error:

```
error: object of type 'std::optional<DecimalEx>' cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted
```

The copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted, because `DecimalEx` has a non static const member. It's obvious, a const value may not be re-assigned. The fix, make it non const:

```
  double m_power;
```

If it does not work for you, then don't copy `DecimalEx` instance to `std::optional<DecimalEx>` but construct it in place of the variable storage:

```
myVariable.emplace(myInitParam);
```

Comment: I had another error:
definition of implicit copy assignment operator for 'DecimalEx' is deprecated because it has a user-declared copy constructor [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-copy]

but after defining

DecimalEx& operator=(const DecimalEx&);

it worked, thanks!

Comment: And a question - what do I do if I want to make the members in the class const (similar to java final) as I don't expect them to change?

Comment: Implement an assignment operator that doesn't change a const member variable.